# Network request failed on react native upload image

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, fetch

I am trying to capture, and upload an image to a server from react native, however I get the following error when I make the http request:

**[TypeError: Network request failed]**

Here is my code, I have followed this tutorial:

https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-upload-images-in-a-react-native-app-4cca03ded855

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image, Button} from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    photo: null,
  };

  createFormData = (photo) => {
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append('photo', {
      name: photo.fileName,
      type: photo.type,
      uri:
        Platform.OS === 'android'
          ? photo.uri
          : photo.uri.replace('file://', ''),
    });

    data.append('id', 1);
    return data;
  };

  handleChoosePhoto = () => {
    const options = {
      noData: true,
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      if (response.uri) {
        this.setState({photo: response});
      }
    });
  };

  handleUploadPhoto = () => {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.104:3000/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: this.createFormData(this.state.photo),
    })
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('upload success', response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('upload error', error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const {photo} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        {photo && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Image
              source={{uri: photo.uri}}
              style={{width: 300, height: 300}}
            />
            <Button title="Upload" onPress={this.handleUploadPhoto} />
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        <Button title="Choose Photo" onPress={this.handleChoosePhoto} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried:

- Add "Content: multipart/form-data" to http request headers
- Add Accept: Accept: application/json" to http request headers

I have noticed that the request fails, only when I add the photo object to the "FormData", that is, the http request runs correctly when I remove the following code:

```js
data.append('photo', {
      name: photo.fileName,
      type: photo.type,
      uri:
        Platform.OS === 'android'
          ? photo.uri
          : photo.uri.replace('file://', ''),
    });
```

#### Edit 02-07-2020

I finally found the solution here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551#issuecomment-610652110

Comment: I'm usign the follow packages

"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1"

The phone I'm developing is a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5

Comment: Have you tried adding 'file://' + photo.path as androird's uri?

Comment: people arriving here due to the "network request failed" error might be interested in reading [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551)

Answer (score 5):

The first issue is with the imageUri itself. If let’s say photo path is /user/.../path/to/file.jpg. Then file picker in android would give imageUri value as file:/user/.../path/to/file.jpg whereas file picker in iOS would give imageUri value as file:///user/.../path/to/file.jpg.

**The solution for the first issue is to use file:// instead of file: in the formData in android.**

The second issue is that we are not using proper mime-type. It is working fine on iOS but not on Android. What makes this worse is that the file-picker package gives the type of the file as “image” and it does not give proper mime-type.

The solution is to use proper mime-type in the formData in the field type. Ex: mime-type for .jpg file would be image/jpeg and for .png file would be image/png. We do not have to do this manually. Instead, you can use a very famous **npm package called mime**.

```
import mime from "mime";

const newImageUri =  "file:///" + imageUri.split("file:/").join("");

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', {
 uri : newImageUri,
 type: mime.getType(newImageUri),
 name: newImageUri.split("/").pop()
});
```

Comment: to get more info on this solution check here : https://forums.expo.dev/t/network-request-failed-while-uploading-image-to-server/30737/5

Comment: you also have to install mime by running - expo install mime or npm install mime

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551#issuecomment-643205642) also works:

> I had same this issue in my project with react-native version 0.62.
> I updated flipper to "0.41.0" and it worked.
>
> In gradle.properities
>
> FLIPPER_VERSION=0.41.0

`gradle.properties` is located at `PROJECT_ROOT/android`

Answer (score 1):

```
const URL = "ANY_SERVER/upload/image"
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url); // the address really doesnt matter the error occures before the network request is even made.
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('image', { uri: image.path, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' });

  xhr.send(data);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = e => {
    if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
      return;
    }

    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log('success', xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      console.log('error', xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue a few days ago.
The problem for me was that **photo.type** return an incorrect type. So i just add it manually.

```
fd.append('documentImages', {
      name: getImgId(img.uri) + '.jpg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      uri: Constants.platform.android
        ? img.uri
        : img.uri.replace('file://', ''),
    })
```

Comment: These are the values ​​they get when I print some properties of the image  

**fileName:** IMG-20200617-WA0022.jpg  
**type:**  image/jpeg   
**uri:**  
 
 content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2FWhatsApp%20Images%2FIMG-20200617-WA0022.jpg

Comment: any error message when de post fails? dont just consol.log the error. inspect the error object, maybe you find useful info there

Answer (score 0):

```
const launchCamera = () => {
  let options = {
    storageOptions: {
      skipBackup: true,
      path: "images",
    },
  };
  ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response) => {
    console.log("Response = ", response);
    if (response.didCancel) {
      console.log("User cancelled image picker");
    } else if (response.error) {
      console.log("ImagePicker Error: ", response.error);
    } else if (response.customButton) {
      console.log("User tapped custom button: ", response.customButton);
      alert(response.customButton);
    } else {
      const source = { uri: response.uri };
      console.log(
        "response in image pleae chec nd xcjn",
        JSON.stringify(response)
      );
      this.setState({
        filePath: response,
        fileData: response.data,
        fileUri: response.uri,
      });
    }
    imageUpload(response);
  });
};

const imageUpload = (imageUri) => {
  console.log('imageuril',imageUri);
  const newImageUri =  "file:///" + imageUri.assets[0].uri.split("file:/").join("");
  const imageData = new FormData()
  imageData.append("file", {
    uri: newImageUri,
    type: mime.getType(newImageUri),
    name: newImageUri.split("/").pop()
  })
  console.log("form data", imageData)
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://example.com/admin/api/v1/upload_reminder/1',
    data: imageData
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("image upload successfully", response.data)
    }).then((error) => {
      console.log("error riased", error)
    })

}
```

**Use this code 100% working**

Comment: import mime from "mime";  install this plugin 100% code working