# Network request failed on uploading multiple images in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, fetch

I'm uploading images through `fetch api`. While uploading, if a single images is selected it works perfectly but if multiple images are selected it gives error `[TypeError: Network request failed]`. i have tried commenting `initializeFlipper` and [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450971/network-request-failed-on-react-native-upload-image) this answer also.
Server takes array of images.. this is how `images[]` looks like when multiple images are selected

```
[{"height": 900, "mime": "image/jpeg", "modificationDate": "1649410153000", "path": "file:///data/user/0/com.emilio/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/FB_IMG_1649005113656.jpg", "size": 78059, "width": 720}, {"height": 4160, "mime": "image/jpeg", "modificationDate": "1649410153000", "path": "file:///data/user/0/com.emilio/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG_20220330_134929_1.jpg", "size": 923567, "width": 1920}]
```

and this is how `images` looks like when single images is selected

```
[{"height": 725, "mime": "image/jpeg", "modificationDate": "1649410757000", "path": "file:///data/user/0/com.emilio/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/FB_IMG_1649089342911.jpg", "size": 51443, "width": 720}]
```

this is my code:

```
  const postOrder = () => {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('marca', marca);
    data.append('modeo', modeo);
    data.append('option', option);
    data.append('description', description);
    data.append('images[]', {
      uri: images,
      name: 'image.jpg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
    });
    data.append('userId', state.user.id);
    dispatch(saveOrder(data));
  };

export const saveOrder = data => dispatch => {
  console.log('/data in order action', data);
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/save-order`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body: data,
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log('json1', json);
      alert('order placed');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error in saving', error);
    });
};
```

**Edit**
checked with postman..multiple images are uploading successfully..this is how postman sending it. does anybody know how should i format images[] param
[image: postman]

Comment: Try my solution https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16451#issuecomment-1051788715

Answer (score 0):

[`TypeError: Network request failed]` is thrown when the parameters you send are not correctly formatted. So try the other way I mentioned below.

Try doing a loop and append

```
images.map((file, index) => {
   data.append(`images[${index}]`, {
      uri: file,
      name: 'image.jpg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
   });
})
```

Also, ask your backend developer to check if they are accepting the file in the correct param and way. Cross-check the same with the postman to confirm.